# How to configure affiliate module in Yii?

Tags: yii, configure, affiliate

I have affiliate module and i put it into Yii protected module folder. Now what will i do for next steps to get affect of this module in my site ?

Note : I don't know about affiliate Program ..... Just need to run this module in my yii site.

Thanks in Advance.

Kavi.

Answer (score 1):

I got some better Solution. And able to rune this module.

Need some External Tool name **couponic**. and then install this module like step vice.

[Click this link for more information](http://uniprogy.com/docs/couponic/couponic-guide)